# C pthread struct creation in a for loop

Tags: c, struct, pthreads, malloc

I'm currently trying to create new struct objects during a for loop. These are being passed onto a new function, which handles them.

```
int start_i = 0;
for(int t = 0 ; t < t_max ; t++) {
    // Arguments for the threads.
    struct arguments* arguments1 = malloc(sizeof(struct arguments));
    arguments1->old_array = old_array;
    arguments1->current_array = current_array;
    arguments1->next_array = next_array;
    arguments1->i_start = start_i;

    if (t == t_max - 1) {
        arguments1->i_end = i_max;
    }
    else {
        arguments1->i_end = start_i + i_size - 1;
        start_i += i_size;
    }

    printf("%d\n", &arguments1);

    pthread_create(&thread_ids[t], NULL, &help, (void*)arguments1);
}
```

As you can see I am using pthreads. The problem is that instead of all objects being new, they just overwrite the old one, as the adres location I print is the very same one. I need the objects to be new, because otherwise different threads will work with shared data.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `arguments1` is a pointer and its address (`&arguments1`) will not vary in the code you've provided. However, what it's *pointing to* will change each time you call `malloc`. Since you're passing the `arguments1` *value* (not `&arguments1` -- its address) as the argument to `pthread_create`, you *are* passing the right thing (a pointer to the newly allocated structure) to your thread function. To see the changing value within your loop, use:

```
printf("%p\n", arguments1);
```

Note that `%p` is the right way to print a pointer value, not `%d`.